# creating maven project without IDE get build faliure

Tags: java, maven

I try to create maven project from command line, i am using apache maven 3.3.3 with jdk 7.

C:\MVN\CubeGenerator>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId= com.mavapp -DartifactId=C
    ubeGenerator -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=
    false

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.169 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-07T00:13:23+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\MVN\CubeGenerator). Please verify you invoked Maven from
the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra spaces after the "=" for two properties. 
I think you want:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mavapp -DartifactId=CubeGenerator -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: i didnt change any spaces i just change in apache-maven->conf-> setting.xml, here i change localrepository  (<localRepository>c:/mavenlocalrepository</localRepository>) with ( <localRepository>c:/mavenlocalrepository</localRepository> ) and its work fine thnx